# C# - How should I design my server?

Tags: c#, networking

I'm confused in designing a TCP server with C#.

- Where should I put my TCP Listener ? inside **Program** class or
  create **Server** class ? or ...
- Where should I start handling client
  ? from **Listener** accept callback or create **ClientHandler** class
  ? or...
- Do **Client** class is responsible for receiving messages or I have to create a separate class ? What should I name that class ? **Receiver** or **Connection** ?
- Where should I keep clients list ? **Server** or **ClientManager** or **Client** class ?

These questions blows my brain every time I do networking. I have more questions but I guess your know it.

Comment: The names don't really matter. Consider writing all your code in the `Main()` first and then extract methods and classes when you see a pattern that looks like it would be better as an object.

Comment: Class design doesn't work the way you think it does.  There are no right or wrong ways to arrange your classes; there is only that arrangement that provides optimal clarity and organization.

Comment: Don't use objects and patterns like rules. Use them like sponges that soak up complexity when it spills out and makes a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are not the only mechanism for creating abstraction.  Packages and namespaces are others.  So, when you have several very related yet differentiated concepts, put them in the same namespace — don't then be afraid of creating too many classes.

One important thing about an individual class is its lifetime in usage.  The class's lifetime and all its instance fields should be the same.  Ideally, each instance field is fully relevant to the object during its whole lifetime.  (Some judgement required: there can be exceptions for an object that takes a few methods to fully initialize, or to fully tear down).

We can work this lifetime cohesiveness thought in either direction:

List all possible concepts and consider them each serious candidates for their own separate class.  Work with it, and, if it turns out that two (or more) of those classes are always being created (and destroyed / let go) together, it suggests that you might merge them together — that can be done by composition, inheritance, or simply merging them into a single concept (removing the other).

Going the other way, you can create just the classes you feel are independent concepts, and split them when you find that inside the class, the instance fields group together such that some of the fields are irrelevant during some of the object's lifetime.

In practice we might find both: sometimes finding cases where we ought to split and others where we ought to merge.  Use the lifetime notion as a guide to help decide when.

---

Ideally (IMHO) we put little to no state in `Program` and the only logic in `main` creates an instance of something useful and activates it — just use `Program`.`main` as a bridge between the non-oo entry point and your object system; that way the rest of your code is fully object-oriented.